# Is it possible to rehydrate an Azure blob that is already pending rehydration?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am wondering if it is possible to rehydrate a blob in Microsoft Azure blob storage (request to change the access tier) if there is already a pending request to change the access tier?

For example, the blob is currently set to Archive and I set the access tier to Cool. After requesting the change, it would take several hours for it to go through. However, what if I change my mind and want to change it to Hot tier instead of Cool or change it back to Archive?

I tried to change it to Hot instead of Cool while it was still pending the first request but received an error where it said it has failed to change access tier for the blob. I looked through Microsoft documentation about this possibility but so far, I could not find anything about that. From the looks of things, it seems that you would have to wait until the initial request is finished before you can request to change the tier again. I am wondering if this is the case or if there is a way to override the initial access tier change request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if this is the case or if there is a way to override
> the initial access tier change request?

It is not possible to do so. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-rehydration?tabs=azure-portal#rehydrate-an-archived-blob-to-an-online-tier):

> **Once a rehydration request is initiated, it cannot be canceled**. During
> the rehydration process, the x-ms-access-tier blob property will
> continue to show as archive until rehydration is completed to an
> online tier.

One thing you could possibly do is copy the archived blob to a new blob in hot tier. However your archived blob will eventually be converted into an accessible blob so you will end up with 2 blobs with same content.